# How can I specify in pom.xml a dependency to a project in a repository?

Tags: maven, dependency-injection, repository, pom.xml, remote-repository

I have a project working on my Spring Tool Suite. Also, I have a project in an innersource repository that I want to use in my project of STS.

For that, I need to specify the dependency in the pom.xml file of my project to establish the dependency with this remote project. But I don't know how to specify this dependency and what information about the remote project I need to put in the pom and where I can find it.

At least I need what information I should write in the pom and I will look wherever for that information.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A [best practice](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) is to use your own / company wide Maven Repository Manager such as Nexus and define a [single repository group](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/maven-repositories#MavenRepositories-ConfiguringApacheMaven).

Use this Maven Repository Manager to share closed source artifacts (hosted repository) and to access Open Source repository such as Maven Central (proxy repository).